# Javascript code to show local browser sqlite database

Tags: javascript, sqlite, local-storage

I need some sort of javascript loop to show all the contents of a local sqlite database in browser.

Database is created and populated already by other javascript code in some other page, so no need to create db, just open the connection, and display all rows in some sort of while loop.

so far I got:

```
 var db = openDatabase("Users");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need : http://code.google.com/p/javascript-client-side-sqlite3-wrapper/

Comment: not really, i already got working the create table and insert info, i need to show the table info, if this thing is able to do it, can you please elaborate how to use it?, thanks.